# Creating Custom Route in MVC3 Razor for Views with in Areas

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a Solution "sample". which has multiple folders a,b,c,d...
My start up project is in c folder.
With in startup project, i have Areas,content,controller,helpers,Models,Views etc folders.
In Areas Folder, I have Area1 and Area2 folders.
With in Area2 i have Controllers, Models and Views

If i run the Project i need to access http://localhost/c/Area2/Home(another Folder)/home(main View)

to get to home page.How can i create Custom Route to View the Home page directly if i run the Solution instead of typing above path manually .

*Names of the Controller and Models are HomeController and HomeModel.

Answer (score 1):

To create a custom route, You will have to add an entry of route in global.asax.cs file

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "FolderName", // Route name
            "FolderName1/FolderName2/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });// Parameter defaults
```

To answer your question, and to make above route as a default one, you may just want to remove the default route which VS puts in global.asax file